# Reshaping x-y data into sub-arrays based on conditions set for x

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two numerical arrays of 6538x1 data, let's say diameter and weight. I would like to create multiple sub-arrays whenever diameter falls within a desired range. For example, my first sub-array should include diameter within a range of 10^0.65 to 10^0.70 and the corresponding weight values. The second sub-array should include diameter within a range of 10^0.70 to 10^0.75 and the corresponding weight values and so on. I would then like to find the mean values of diameter and weight from each sub-array and create a plot that shows correlations between the two.

I have tried creating a logical index and then finding average values of diameter that fall in the desired range. For example, the lines below can generate average values of diameter for my first desired sub-array but how can I get the corresponding values of weight and calculate the mean for that?

```
subarray1 = diameter <10^0.7 & diameter>=10^0.65;
meandiameter1 = mean(diameter(subarray1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the diameter ranges are defined by a set of edges that span the full set of data, this can be easily done with

- [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) to classify the diameters in ranges, and then
- [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to apply a function to the diameters or to the weights for each range of diameters.

```
diameters = [4 7 2 8 7 9 6 4 6 8 4 3];
weights = [10 40 50 40 30 60 70 80 90 40 20 60];
edges = [2 4 6 8 10]; % first range is [edges(1), edges(2)),
                      % second is [edges(2), edges(3)), ...,
                      % last is [edges(end), inf]
[~, ~, ind] = histcounts(diameters, [edges inf]);
result_diameters = accumarray(ind(:), diameters(:), size(edges(:)), @mean, NaN);
result_weights = accumarray(ind(:), weights(:), size(edges(:)), @mean, NaN);
```

For example, this gives

```
result_weights =
  55.000000000000000
  36.666666666666664
  57.500000000000000
  46.666666666666664
                 NaN
```

`result_weights(1)` is `55`, which is the average weight for the two values with diameter in the range [`2`, `4`), namely the third and last data values. `result_weights(5)` is `NaN` because there are no values in the range [`10`, `inf`].

Comment: Thank you Luis Mendo. I was able to use your suggestion for finding mean values of both dimeter and range for the entire dataset.

Answer (score 1):

`subarray1` is a logical array telling you which elements to select that fulfil your conditions. Just like you use logical indexing with `diameter` to select the diameters that are in the range, you can use it with your `weight` array to give you the weights corresponding to the diameters that are in your range.

```
meanweight1 = mean(weight(subarray1));
```

To do this using a loop for multiple ranges, you could do something like this:

```
diameter_ranges = [0.65 0.70; 
                   0.70 0.75;
                   0.75 0.80];

mean_diameters = zeros(size(diameter_ranges, 1), 1);
mean_weights = zeros(size(diameter_ranges, 1), 1);

for ii = 1:shape(diameter_ranges, 1)
    filter_selection = diameter >= diameter_ranges(ii, 0) & diameter < diameter_ranges(ii, 1);
    mean_diameters = mean(diameter(filter_selection));
    mean_weights = mean(weight(filter_selection));
end

plot(mean_diameters, mean_weights);
```

Comment: Thank you Pranav Hosangadi. I was able to use the logical subarray1 to find the mean values of both diameter and weight. However, when I try the loop method, I get an error message that shape is not a recognized function or variable. Do you happen to know how this can be resolved?

Comment: @Ari I think it should be `size` rather than `shape`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo, I had python on my mind :)